# Embedded fonts with hiqpdf

Tags: html, css, fonts, hiqpdf

I'm trying to generate a pdf from html by using Hiqpdf. As they say in the website: http://www.hiqpdf.com/documentation/html/037cb13e-febe-4d08-a90c-a08bbd5a4348.htm this dll supports fonts embedding. However, I'm using the following fonts stored in my computer and it doesn't work.

```
@font-face {
font-style:normal;
font-weight:normal;
font-family:f2generic;
src:url('C:/Users/myuser/AppData/Local/Temp/f2generic.otf')  format("opentype");}
```

I don't know is it is something wrong with the path (as it must be absolute path or the format of the font). In html format i can display the fonts right.

I checked property htmlToPdfConverter.Document.FontEmbedding and it is true, so I don't know why it doesn't work.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You should try to use fully qualified URLs for resources like `file:///C:/Users/myuser/AppData/Local/Temp/f2generic.otf`